# Store data in Android using Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

In application there is menu in menu user can choose one of them. All required data from server. Where should I make an request and store data? 
So far I made request inside fragment, but I do not want to make request per activity/fragment.

Is the good idea to make request inside main activity (of course using other thread <>). And then keep data in **static list** in this activity? Or is there better way to store this data?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very vague question, the answer can vary by a lot based on the precise requirements.

For example if its just a boolean returned by server, sure you can save as static boolean, if the list returned is small, sure save it as static, as long as you are comfortable with loosing the data when the app is killed.

If not you need to save the data somewhere, depending on the size, type there are multiple options you can use please read http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you ment using Volley as a Singleton class read more in the following [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/).